# Symbolicate exception of UWP app built with .NET Native

Tags: c#, uwp, symbolicatecrash, .net-native, sideloading

In the logs of a sideloaded Windows Store App, I find the following exception:

`Arg_ArgumentException --> System.ArgumentException: Arg_ArgumentException
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3a13ad
   at my-app!<BaseAddress>+0xf29d82h
   at my-app!<BaseAddress>+0xf29cdc
   at my-app!<BaseAddress>+0x10e0844
   at my-app!<BaseAddress>+0x14fbe60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x502089
   at System.Threading.ContextCallback.Invoke(Object state)
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3e683c`

To symbolicate the trace, I tried to utilize the [WindowsDevCenterStacktraceSymbolicater](https://github.com/hig-dev/WindowsDevCenterStacktraceSymbolicater) and the [StackParser](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-tools/tree/master/src/StackParser) of the corefx-tools along with the PDB of the app, which will change the trace to:

`Arg_ArgumentException --> System.ArgumentException: Arg_ArgumentException
   at SharedLibrary!COM+_Entry_Point+0x3a13ad
   at my-app!COM+_Entry_Point+0xf29d82
   at my-app!COM+_Entry_Point+0xf29cdc
   at my-app!COM+_Entry_Point+0x10e0844
   at my-app!COM+_Entry_Point+0x14fbe60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SharedLibrary!COM+_Entry_Point+0x502089
   at System.Threading.ContextCallback.Invoke(Object state)
   at SharedLibrary!COM+_Entry_Point+0x3e683c`

Is there a way to resolve the `COM+_Entry_Point` references in this scenario? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the PDB placed in the output folder of your app, use the PDB file placed in the `ilc` subdirectory (which is way larger). With this PDB, the stack trace will properly be symbolicated using one of the tools mentioned above.